# Xcode 8.3 nvalid bitcode signature

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]
[image]

My project use P2PCamera SDK，but not use Cocoapod，then need depend more lib

`error: Invalid bitcode signature
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I can build and run success in Xcode8.2,but is error when i use Xcode8.3

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue when I tried to test with iOS device.The debug configuration with Build Active Architecture Only is set to NO. After I set to YES, I can test with my iPhone. [image]
This will resolve the issue surely.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the issue because of a third party SDK integrated into your project using Cocoapods.
do the following:

- Clear `derived data` & restart `Xcode`.
- Clean & Build.

Or if you don't mind disabling bitcode: Go to build settings search bitcode and change "`Enable Bitcode`" to "`No`".

Comment: @OdedHarth May i know which pods you are using ?

Comment: @OdedHarth All right you can do like create a new project & install one by one pod & yeah you can find root cause of your problem.

Comment: @OdedHarth you are using too many pods - you can use Alamofire inbuilt functionality for checking internet `let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

manager?.listener = { status in
    print("Network Status Changed: \(status)")
}

manager?.startListening()` . try to minimize uses of pods by using specific files from pods.

Comment: I no use cocoapod,but i use third party SDK with c++,and Bitcode is No

Comment: I've just found that the cause of the problem for me was dlib (a c++ library). Should I recompile it to solve this?

Comment: is P2PCamera SDK

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with **lAVCtrl_armv7** third party library, you can confirm this by editing valid Architecture to **arm64** and re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to "update project to recommended settings" & clean:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336130/1884907