# Xcode 8.2.1+ Fails Building : Invalid bitcode signature

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

So after updating my Xcode from 8.2.1 to any new version, I'm unable to build/run my project. This is the error that I'm getting..

```
Ld Smash_Anarchy.build/Deployment-iphoneos/Smash\ Anarchy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Smash\ Anarchy normal arm64
cd /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Users/henrik/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/henrik/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Users/henrik/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Users/henrik/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.1.sdk -L/Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS -F/Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS -filelist /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/Smash_Anarchy.build/Deployment-iphoneos/Smash\ Anarchy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Smash\ Anarchy.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/Smash_Anarchy.build/Deployment-iphoneos/Smash\ Anarchy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Smash\ Anarchy_lto.o -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/Smash\ Anarchy.app/Smash\ Anarchy -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -framework SafariServices -weak_framework GLKit -weak_framework CoreBluetooth -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework WebKit -licucore -weak_framework AddressBook -lsqlite3 -lc++ -weak_framework GoogleToolboxForMac -weak_framework FirebaseAnalytics -weak_framework FirebaseAuth -weak_framework FirebaseCore -weak_framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -weak_framework FirebaseCrash -weak_framework FirebaseDatabase -weak_framework FirebaseDynamicLinks -weak_framework FirebaseInstanceID -weak_framework FirebaseNanoPB -weak_framework GTMSessionFetcher -weak-lxml2 -weak-lz -weak_framework Accelerate -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AddressBookUI -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreAudio -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -weak_framework CoreData -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework CoreImage -weak_framework CoreMIDI -framework Appodeal -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework EventKit -weak_framework EventKitUI -weak_framework ExternalAccessory -weak_framework iAd -weak_framework ImageIO -weak_framework MediaToolbox -weak_framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenAL -weak_framework QuickLook -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework CoreMedia -framework Foundation -framework FirebaseRemoteConfig -weak_framework GameKit -framework MediaPlayer -weak_framework MessageUI -weak_framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/S3DClient_iOS.a -framework Protobuf /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/Plugins/jpCloudEnvironment_iOS.a /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/Plugins/jpEventQueue_iOS.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/Smash_Anarchy.build/Deployment-iphoneos/Smash\ Anarchy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Smash\ Anarchy_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/henrik/Desktop/iOS_Workspace/SmashAnarchy/Smash_Anarchy_iOS/Smash_Anarchy.build/Deployment-iphoneos/Smash\ Anarchy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Smash\ Anarchy

error: Invalid bitcode signature
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how to get rid of this error? My bitcode isn't even on. I've tried enabling, disabling it, cleaning the derived data, cleaning project, restarting Xcode, setting the "Build Active Architecture Only" to YES, and NO.. nothing helped... I'm not using pod...
Any idea how to find the reason of this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to change your default xcode:
just Follow these steps:

1. Go to Preference.

   [image]
2. Go to Location.

   [image]
3. Change command line.

   [image]

--- also if its not work then you have to remove DerivedData, if no success then reinstall pod if exist.

Comment: tried changing the command line tools.. didn't helped.. removing the Derived Data didn't worked too.. not using any pod.. :(

Comment: go to build settings and disable BitCode after that remove derived data also clean project then run

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this (Xcode 9.0):

- "Update project to recommended settings" - for both the project and Cococapods. I was seeing this when trying to build for iOS 8 and 9 only so I think it had something to do with my old project's cocoapods having iOS 7 as a deployment target.
- Clean
- Quit Xcode
- Delete build folder
- Delete derived data

When I reopened Xcode it built fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change scheme target Generic iOS device to real device (ex. your iPhone)

It works in my case but I have no idea why it does

Im on Xcode 9.0 and with some frameworks(include custom code)